# JRuby Community Support

Tags: jruby

We are exercising various technology or framework options to develop our new portal or web-application on elearning. So the favourites on the list are (not in any specific order)
1. Rails
2. J2EE
3. JRuby

So wanted inputs on the JRuby community support if we get to choose JRuby framework. Also want to know JRuby advantages.  I have gone through some of the coolest advantage of JRuby, still want to konw if I missed something
1. Threading => Scalabity
2. Performance 2.5 times faster
3. Usage of both what java and ruby got to offer
4. Unicode support of Java etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're comparing a web development framework (Rails) with a enterprise development and deployment platform (J2EE) and a language implementation (JRuby).

If you develop a rails app and deploy it using warbler & glassfish then you'll be using all three things!

Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: Yep. So its like develop rails app using rails framework which inturn uses ruby and use some tool to package it into war and deploy it on application web server which has a Ruby interpreter written in Java which is JRuby?. So Glassfish comes with JRuby? Thoroughly confused

Comment: No Glassfish is separate.  It's one of the options for deploying a JRuby on Rails app (as is Tomcat).  However if you download netbeans (an IDE) you get built-in JRuby and Glassfish, but this is really a matter of convenience rather than requirement.